# jQuery library-like pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wanting to develop a library following some interesting patterns of jQuery (Builder and Prototype, basically). I tried to read the jQuery source and search for tutorials but did not get anywhere.

My idea is to allow access of this type:

- `grace(...)` is callable directly
- `grace.set(...)` can have methods
- `grace.fn.get = ...` can set new methods

[**The most I got was this**](http://jsfiddle.net/J825H/):

```
(function(window, undefined) {

    "use strict";

    //
    var grace = function(options) {
        return new grace.fn.init(options);
    };

    //
    grace.fn = grace.prototype = {
        //
        set: function() {
            alert("grace.set() OK");
        },

        //
        init: function() {
            alert("grace() OK");
        },
    };

    //
    window.grace = grace;

})(window);
```

It is callable directly, but their methods are not accessible.

Comment: Copy all `grace.fn` properties to the `grace`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/J825H/1/

Comment: `window.grace = grace.fn;` http://jsfiddle.net/J825H/2/

Answer (score 2):

An `extend` method is supposed to add to `grace` and `grance.fn`, and when you want to add new methods to `grace`, use `grace.extend`; when you want to add new methods to instances that `grace()` creates, use `grace.fn.extend`. Take a look at code below:

```
(function(window, undefined) {
   "use strict";

    var grace = function(options) {
        return new grace.fn.init(options);
    };

    grace.fn = grace.prototype = {
        init: function() {
            alert("grace() OK");
        },
    };

    grace.extend = grace.fn.extend = function() {/* code here */}

    grace.extend({ // add new methods to grace itself
        set: function() {
            alert("grace.set() OK");
        }
    })

    grace.fn.extend({
       /* add new methods to instances that grace() creates */
    })

    grace.fn.init.prototype = grance.fn;
    window.grace = grace;

})(window);
```

**Note:** `grace.fn.init.prototype = grance.fn` is needed because `new grace.fn.init(options)` will get an object inherits methods from `grace.init.prototype`. Without that line of code, you won't get these methods of `grace.fn`.

Sorry for my poor english, and sorry for not having runnable code. Hope code above will inspire you.